# insert data in to database which is in edittext

Tags: android, sqlite, button, insert, android-edittext

i am new to android help me pls,i have 4 editbox and i button i want to store  the contents of the all the 4 edittext when i click the save button.when click the detail button already stored edittext value in the database is to view in another activity in a list view..pls help

Comment: @user555910 you should first do google and you will be having more stuff regarding DATABASE Examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to see some code to respond effectively. But just check the notepad example, it's quite straight forward and shows the main uses of a database on Android....

This is basically the code to store a new element in the DB:

```
    public long createAppEntry(String name) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEVICE_NAME, name);

         return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_DEVICES, null, initialValues);
    }
```

And here is how I get the values:

> private void saveState() {
>           String s1 = contentEditText.getText().toString();
>           myDBAdapter.createAppEntry(1s1);
>       }

but again, just check the Notepad app if you need more detail...